# How to full height left sidebar in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a admin dashboard panel where collapsible left sidebar present. But problem is if i scroll window the left sidebar is not full height. I have set the wrapper and body min-height 100%. But it does not work.

css code:

```
body{
      background: #f5f6f8;
      color: #494949;
      min-height: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  #wrapper {
      padding-left: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled {
      padding-left: 230px;
  }

  #sidebar-wrapper {
      z-index: 1000;
      position: absolute;
      left: 230px;
      width: 0;
      margin-left: -230px;
      background-color: #fff; /*#222d32;*/
        color: white;
        white-space: nowrap!important;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      top:0;
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
      width: 230px;
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 15px;
      padding-top: 50px;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      margin-right: -230px;
  }
  /* Sidebar Styles */

  /*metis menu*/

  .arrow {
  float: right;
  }
  .glyphicon.arrow:before {
  content: "\e079";
  }
  .active > a > .glyphicon.arrow:before {
  content: "\e114";
  }
  .fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f104";
  }
  .active > a > .fa.arrow:before {
  content: "\f107";
  }
  .plus-times {
  float: right;
  }
  .fa.plus-times:before {
  content: "\f067";
  }
  .active > a > .fa.plus-times {
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .plus-minus {
  float: right;
  }
  .fa.plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f067";
  }
  .active > a > .fa.plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f068";
  }


  /*----end of icon--*/


  .sidebar-header{
    color: #4b646f;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 5px 12px 15px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 230px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
  }


  .sidebar-nav li a {
    color: #737373;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 3px solid transparent;
    padding: 12px 15px 12px 15px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav>li>a {
      border-top: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  }
  .sidebar-nav>li.active>a, .sidebar-nav>li:hover>a {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-left: 3px solid #23b7e5;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #484343;
  }
  .sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper.sidebar-toggle {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    margin-left: -230px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav>li>.submenu {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0 1px;
      padding: 4px 4px 4px 14px;
      font-size: 12px;
      background-color: #fbfbfb;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.15),inset 0 -4px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.15),inset 0 -4px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
      box-shadow: inset 0 4px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.15),inset 0 -4px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  }
  .sidebar-nav>li>.submenu a{
        color: #737373;
  }

  .sidebar-nav .submenu>li>a:hover {
      color: #484343;
  }
  .sidebar-nav .fa, .submenu>li>a>.glyphicon{
      width: 20px;
  }




  .main-header{
      position: relative;
      max-height: 100px;
      z-index: 1030;
  }

  .main-header .logo {
      background-color: #1FABD6;
      color: #fff;
      border-bottom: 0 solid transparent;
      -webkit-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: width .3s ease-in-out;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      height: 50px;
      font-size: 20px;
      line-height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 230px;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
      padding: 0 15px;
      font-weight: 300;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  .main-header>.navbar {
      -webkit-transition: margin-left .3s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: margin-left .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: margin-left .3s ease-in-out;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-left: 230px;
      border: none;
      min-height: 50px;
      border-radius: 0;
      background-color: #23b7e5;
      padding-right: 20px;

  }


  .main-header .toggleBtn {
      float: left;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: none;
      padding: 15px;
      font-family: fontAwesome;
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  .main-header .toggleBtn:before {
      content: "\f0c9";
  }
  .main-header .navbar .toggleBtn,.main-header .navbar .nav>li>a  {
      color: #fff;
  }
  .main-header .navbar .nav .open>a, .main-header .navbar .nav .open>a:focus, .main-header .navbar .nav .open>a:hover, .main-header .navbar .nav>.active>a, .main-header .navbar .nav>li>a:active, .main-header .navbar .nav>li>a:focus, .main-header .navbar .nav>li>a:hover {
      background: #1FABD6;
      color: #f6f6f6;
  }

  .main-header .navbar .toggleBtn:hover {
      color: #f6f6f6;
      background-color: #1FABD6;
      text-decoration: none;
  }

  .main-header .navbar .cust-nav .navbar-nav{
    float: right;
  }


  .cust-nav .navbar-nav>li {
      float: left;
  }
  .cust-nav .navbar-nav {
      margin: 0;
      float: left;
  }
  .cust-nav .navbar-nav>li>a {
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      line-height: 20px;
  }


  .cust-nav .navbar-nav .dropdown:hover> a .label {
    animation: none;
    -webkit-animation: none;
  }


  .main-header .navbar .nav>li>a>.label {
      position: absolute;
      top: 9px;
      right: 7px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 9px;
      padding: 2px 3px;
      line-height: .9;
      animation: opacity-badge 1s infinite;
      -webkit-animation: opacity-badge 1s infinite;
  }
  @keyframes opacity-badge {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0.5);-webkit-filter: opacity(.1); filter: opacity(.1);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1.8); 
    }
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes opacity-badge {
    0% {
      transform: scale(0.5);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(0.5);-webkit-filter: opacity(.1); filter: opacity(.1);

    }
  }
  .cust-nav>.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
      position: absolute;
      right: 5%;
      left: auto;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      background: #fff;
  }



  /*===========================content header===============================*/
  .content-header{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 39px;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;

  }

  .content-header h1 {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 4px;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: lighter;
      color: #737373;
      line-height: 37px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding-left: 10px;
  }

  .breadcrumb {
      background-color: transparent;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 37px;
      margin: 0 22px 0 12px;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 13px;
      color: #333;
      border-radius: 0;
  }
  .breadcrumb>li>i {
      margin-left: 4px;
      margin-right: 2px;
      font-size: 20px;
      position: relative;
      top: 2px;
  }
  .breadcrumb>li, .breadcrumb>li.active {
      color: #777;
      -webkit-text-shadow: none;
      text-shadow: none;
  }
  .breadcrumb>li>a {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #2dc3e8;
  }

  /*===========================info box===============================*/

  .info-orange{
    border-left: 5px solid #FF8B24;
    color: #FF8B24;
  }

  .info-sky{
    border-left: 5px solid #23B7E5;
    color: #23B7E5;
  }

  .info-red{
    border-left: 5px solid #F11212;
    color: #F11212;
  }

  .info-green{
    border-left: 5px solid #2CDE00;
    color: #969594;
  }

  hr{
    border-top: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
  }
  .info-box{
    min-height: 90px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius: 4px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .info-left{
    float:left;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #9C9C9C;
  }
  .info-left h2{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
  .info-right{
    float:right;
  }

  /*===========================panel===============================*/
  .panel-default{

  }


  @media(max-width: 768px){

    .main-header .logo, .main-header .navbar {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      position: relative!important;
      margin-left: 0px;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper{
      padding-top: 100px!important;

    }

    .main-header .navbar .cust-nav{
      float: left;
      padding-left: 20%;
    }

    .cust-nav>.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
      position: absolute;
      right: -60%;
      left: auto;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      background: #fff;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
      padding-top: 100px;
    }

    .content-header{
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
  }


  @media(min-width:768px) {
      #wrapper {
          padding-left: 250px;
      }

      #wrapper.toggled {
          padding-left: 0;
      }

      #sidebar-wrapper {
          width: 230px;
      }

      #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
          width: 0;
      }

      #page-content-wrapper {
          padding: 20px;
          position: relative;
      }

      #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
          position: relative;
          margin-right: 0;
      }
  }
```

html:

```
        <a href="" class="logo">
                <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
                <span class="logo-lg"><b>Demo</b></span>
            </a>

        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation" id="mainNav">
          <a href="" class="toggleBtn visible-xs1" role="button" id="menu-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                </a>


                <div class="cust-nav">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- Messages-->
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                            <span class="label label-success">4</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li class="header">You have 4 messages</li>
                          <li>Test</li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>

                      <!-- Notifications-->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                            <span class="label label-warning">10</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li class="header">You have 10 notifications</li>
                          <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <!-- Settings-->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li class="header">You have 10 notifications</li>
                          <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>

        </div>
      </div>


    <!-- page wraper -->
    <div id="wrapper">



      <!-- sidebar wrapper -->
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">


          <li class="sidebar-header">SideBar</li>
            <li><a href="#item1"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#item1"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> Settings</a></li>



          <!-- Users menu -->
          <li>
            <a href="#" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-users"></i> 
                User
              <i class="fa arrow pull-right"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i><span> Create New</span></a></li>
              <li><a href=""> <i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span> View Users</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li><!--End of  Users menu -->



            <li><a href="#item1"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Message</a></li>
            <li><a href="#item1"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Log</a></li>


              </ul>
          </div><!-- //sidebar wrapper -->


           <!-- Page Content -->
          <div id="page-content-wrapper">

            <div class="content-header">
          <h1>Dashboard</h1>
          <ul class="breadcrumb pull-right hidden-xs">
                      <li>
                          <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                          <a href="#">Home</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="active">Dashboard</li>
                  </ul>
        </div>
        <hr/>


              <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <!--info box -->
                          <div class="row">
                      <!--client panel -->
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="info-box info-orange">
                          <div class="info-left">
                      <span>Demo1</span>
                      <h2>100</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-right">
                      <i class="fa fa-institution fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <!--Student panel -->
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="info-box info-sky">
                          <div class="info-left">
                      <span>Demo2</span>
                      <h2>500</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-right">
                      <i class="fa fa-users fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>


                      <!--Message panel -->
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 clerefix">
                        <div class="info-box info-red">
                          <div class="info-left">
                      <span>Total Message</span>
                      <h2>200</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-right">
                      <i class="fa fa-users fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <!--Message panel -->
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="info-box info-green">
                          <div class="info-left">
                      <img src="images/admin.png" class="img-responsive img-circle">
                    </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--info box -->
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                              <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                  Demo Panel Heading
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                  panel body
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    </div><!--//page wrapper-->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/81t6a96j/

Answer (score 1):

The height of the sidebar is 100%, however, when you scroll down the page, the height of the page becomes more than 100%. The sidebar's height won't increase to match the page's height. Thus, change the sidebar's position property to `position:fixed`.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 230px;
 ....
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81t6a96j/2/)

Comment: At first I set the position fixed, but when I scroll it  as my navigation bar is not fixed so it stay on same position. If I set too many sidebar list item it will show vartical scrollbar, I can't set sidebar property to hidden. That's why I set position value absolute.

Answer (score -2):

To have a full height sidebar you must put a height in percent for all parent of your element as you can see in the following example :

```
<html style="height:100%">
    <body style="height:100%">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%">
            <div class="row" style="height:100%">
                <div class="sidebar col-xs-4" style="height:100%"></div>
                <div class="content col-xs-8"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the parent of the sidebar are html, body and wrapper, all are set height:100% and min-height:100%

Comment: You must have forget some element to put at 100% height. As you can see in this codepen it works. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeEXZy
Use console tool of your browser to see which element is not a 100% height in the parents of your sidebar.

Comment: @YvonnickFRIN this doesn't work in real life. let say that we have very long content inside div with blue background from your codepen example, and the result will look like this - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpywMZ

Comment: @Sergey Sure, you just have to add an overflow-y: auto on the div with blue background to make it works. My bad.